# C# find xml element matching two element levels using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to select an XElement from an xml document and match on two "levels" of the xml document. my file structure is:

```
<app>
  <Library Name="Main" Path="C:\somefile.Xml">
    <ReadingList Name="Test1">
      <Book>...
    <ReadingList Name="Test2">
      <Book>...
  <Library Name="Backup" Path="C:\somefile.Xml">
```

And I want to find the reading list name "test2" in library "Main" so I can copy this element and all child elements to another Library node.

I would prefer a solution using linq as I am trying to learn this.

Thanks in advance for any help

When I add a new "reading list" I do it this way:

```
public void AddReadingList(string fullyQualifiedPath, Library lib, string name)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fullyQualifiedPath);

    XElement library = xdoc.Element("eStack").Elements("Library")
                .Single(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == lib.Name);

    library.Add(new XElement("ReadingList", new XAttribute("Name", name)));

    xdoc.Save(fullyQualifiedPath);                        
}
```

but the operation I want to perform is a copy of this element and sub elements. The problem is, there may be more than one "library" element with the same name so I need to check the library name and reading list name. does that make sense?

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of `.Descendants` and `Where`s will do the trick:

```
var result = XDocument.Load(fullyQualifiedPath)
     .Descendants("Library")
         //Can replace with `FirstOrDefault` if you know there is only one
     .Where(element => element.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "Main") 
     .Descendants("ReadingList")
     .Where(element => element.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "Test2").ToList();
```

You can also use `.Elements` instead of `Descendants` I just preferred to use it so to not specify also the level of `app` or any other along the way.

---

For prior c# 6.0 you can do:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
     .Descendants("Library")
     .Where(element =>
     {
        var att = element.Attribute("Name");
        return att != null ? (att.Value == "Main" ? true : false) : false;
     })
     .Descendants("ReadingList")
         //Make sure to do above change here too
     .Where(element => element.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "Test2").ToList();
```

Or if creating a method to help with it instead of repeating the code:

```
 Func<XElement, string, string> tryGetAttributeValue = (element, attributeName) =>
 {
    var attribute = element.Attribute(attributeName);
    return attribute == null ? string.Empty : attribute.Value;
 };

 var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
     .Descendants("Library")
     .Where(element => tryGetAttributeValue(element,"Name") == "Main")
     .Descendants("ReadingList")
     .Where(element => tryGetAttributeValue(element, "Name") == "Test2").ToList();
```

Comment: .Value in your where statement doesn't seem to work. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: I'm getting an Invalid expression term '.' on the .Value on both .Where parts. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @cbutler - Yes. What c# are you using? I assume you are prior to c# 6.0 and therefore the `?.` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Awesome thanks! I really appreciate the help. Your solution for prior to C# 6.0 works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
        var table = XElement.Parse(@"<app>
                                        <Library Name=""Main"" Path=""C:\somefile.Xml"">
                                            <ReadingList Name=""Test1"">
                                                <Book>Book1</Book>
                                            </ReadingList>
                                            <ReadingList Name=""Test2"">
                                                <Book>Book2</Book>
                                            </ReadingList>
                                        </Library>
                                        <Library Name=""Backup"" Path=""C:\somefile.Xml""></Library>
                                    </app>");


        var readingList = table
            .Elements("Library")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "Main")
            .Elements("ReadingList")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("Name")?.Value == "Test2");
```

This would essentially solve your query of getting a `ReadingList` that is named `Test2` and under a `ReadingList` named `Test 1`.

You can opt for `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault` but that would end up with a list of all possible matches.

```
        var readingList = table
            .Elements("Library")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Main")
            .Elements("ReadingList")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Test2")
            .ToList();
```

Opting for a descendant variant would end up in lesser lookup of course.

```
        var readingList = table
            .Descendants("Library")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Main")
            .Descendants("ReadingList")
            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == "Test2")
            .ToList();
```

Comment: The `?.` operator before the second `Descendants`/`Elements` is not needed - it will never be null. If not found it'll be an `Enumerable.Empty`

Comment: True, didn't notice that. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this query:

```
var query=  xdoc.Descendants("Library")
                .Where(e=>e.Attribute("Name").Value=="Main")
                .SelectMany(e=>e.Elements("ReadingList").Where(t=>t.Attribute("Name").Value=="Test2"));
```

If there are just one `Main` element you can also use `FirstOrDefault` extension method:

```
var query=  xdoc.Descendants("Library")
                .FirstOrDefault(e=>e.Attribute("Name").Value=="Main")
                .Descendants("ReadingList").Where(t=>t.Attribute("Name").Value=="Test2"));
```